# In C#, can we add methods into a public Behaviour class without touching it?

Tags: c#, behavior

In *Unity csharp*, I want to make a `GetOrAddComponent` method, which will simplify the respectives `GetComponent` and `AddComponent` (for no good reason I suppose).

The usual way is this:

```
// this is just for illustrating a context
using UnityEngine;
class whatever : MonoBehavior {
public Transform child;
void whateverMethod () {

    BoxCollider boxCollider = child.GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
    if (boxCollider == null) {
        boxCollider = child.gameObject.AddComponent<BoxCollider>();
    }

}}
```

Right now I could make this class . . . :

```
public class MyMonoBehaviour : MonoBehaviour {

    static public Component GetOrAddComponent (Transform child, System.Type type) {
        Component result = child.GetComponent(type);
        if (result == null) {
            result = child.gameObject.AddComponent(type);
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

. . . So this works:

```
// class whatever : MyMonoBehavior {

BoxCollider boxCollider = GetOrAddComponent(child, typeof(BoxCollider)) as BoxCollider;
```

But I wish I could write it like this:

```
BoxCollider boxCollider = child.GetOrAddComponent<BoxCollider>();
```

The only idea I could come up with would be way too complicated to do it (replacing each `Transform` with a `MyTransform`) and thus not worth the trouble of even trying. At least not just for a nicer syntax.

But is it? Or is there any other way this could be achieved?

Comment: There, this is my final result, thanks to *Botz3000*: http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/GetOrAddComponent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried using [Extension Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)? You can declare them like this:

```
public static class MyMonoExtensions {

    public static T GetOrAddComponent<T>(this Transform child) where T: Component {
        T result = child.GetComponent<T>();
        if (result == null) {
            result = child.gameObject.AddComponent<T>();
        }
        return result;
    }

}
```

You can call it like an instance method, then:

```
child.GetOrAddComponent<BoxCollider>();
```

See the link above for more details on extension methods.

Comment: Just to say that these only look like part of the extended type (IDE magic) - they are completely separate.

Comment: @Oded: but that's probably what OP wanted anyway. If there were no extension methods, a static method like this would be perfectly suitable, although much less discoverable through IDE.

Comment: @Dilbert - True and I didn't say it wasn't. I just wanted to note that an extension method is syntactic sugar.

Comment: I have indeed not thought of using Extension Methods, even though I've stumbled upon it before! :P

Answer (score 2):

You can use extension methods since c# 3.0

```
public static MonoBehaviourExtension
{
     public static void GetOrAdd(this MonoBehaviour thisInstance, <args>)
     {
           //put logic here
     }
}
```

Comment: Just to say that these only _look_ like part of the extended type (IDE magic) - they are completely separate.

Comment: @Oded As far as i understand, the extension method is compiled just like a 'regular' method, that is, the first argument it's the instance itself. From the IDE point of view, yes it is a kind of magic, but it reflects what will be done from the runtime perspective

Comment: An extension method compiles to a separate type from what it "extends". It is a static method and the IDE makes it look as if it belongs to the extended type.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Extension methods.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static T GetOrAddComponent<T>(this Transform child) where T : Component 
    {
            T result = child.GetComponent<T>();
            if (result == null) {
                result = child.gameObject.AddComponent<T>();
            }
            return result;
    }
}
```

Now you can use `BoxCollider boxCollider = child.GetOrAddComponent<BoxCollider>();`